# Number of linear inequalities describing a polyhedron with prescribed number of vertices

Tags: co.combinatorics, polyhedra

If a polytope has $d$ vertices in $k$ dimensions how many linear inequalities is required to describe it?

Comment: It depends on the polytope. Do you mean the maximum with fixed $d, k$?

Comment: Smallest and maximum.

Answer (score 1):

Since the span of $n$ points has dimension at most $n-1$, each face of dimension $k-1$ (hyperplane) must contain at least $k$ vertices. So the number of faces of maximal dimension $k-1$ is at most
$$\frac{d!}{k!(d-k)!},$$
the binomial coefficient. This becomes an equality for simplices.

Comment: Is there a notion of minimality?

Comment: Say, if $k=2$, the answer is $d$, not $d(d-1)/2$

Comment: @FedorPetrov What is the general situation for minimality?

Comment: Maximum number of facets is achieved for a cyclic polytope, this is a famous result by P. McMullen https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematika/article/maximum-numbers-of-faces-of-a-convex-polytope/13483049ECEDF0F2D760C50BAE8D6F21#

Comment: What Fedor says is of course true, but might be worth adding that the cyclic polytopes simultaneously maximize the face numbers of all dimensions at once.